# jquery object executing object's assigned function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

This is a simplified version.

If I do something like this:

```
var object = [{name:"bob", type:"silly", hair:"brown", func:someFunction},
              {name:"greg", type:"serious", hair:"blonde", func: differentFunction}]; 

$('#thing').bind("click", object[0], handleTranslator);

function handleTranslator(e){
    $([e.data.func]);
}

function someFunction(){
    console.log("clicking bob should trigger this function");
}

function differentFunction(){
    console.log("clicking greg should trigger this function");
}
```

When I click #thing, it should trigger `someFunction` but it doesn't. Not sure why.

Ideally, I'd like to also be able to see (console.log) my object[0] from inside `someFunction`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @AlienWebguy This is a simplified example.

Comment: @ExplosionPills #thing is already in the dom

Comment: I'm assuming $([e.data.func]); is what is wrong. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: why are you wrapping functions in `$()` ?

Comment: @charlietfl I was trying different things - didn't know the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not invoking your function:

```
function handleTranslator(e){
    e.data.func();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CEdvt/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'func' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: This works... I tried it originally but I think I had my function in quote like: "differentFunction"  TY